# Solve no unused Expression Error with out disabling eslint?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, eslint

I am using react. I have a function that concatenates the keys of an object and returns the result as a string. I am getting a error that looks like this:
Line 64:7:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions

The function that I have is shown below.

```
const allConcat = (listOfObj) => {
    let stringConcat = '';
    Object.keys(listOfObj).map((item, i)=>{
      (listOfObj[item] === 1)? stringConcat += item : null
    });
    return stringConcat
  }
```

Here is a for each version and i am also getting an error for this.

```
  const allConcat = (listOfObj) => {
    let stringConcat = '';
    Object.keys(listOfObj).forEach(item =>{
      (listOfObj[item] === 1)? stringConcat += item : null
    });
    return stringConcat
  }
```

Please let me know what I can do to get rid of this error. Besides disabling the linter.

Comment: I've changed my code to use for each and am still getting this error.

Comment: `const allConcat = (listOfObj) => {
    let stringConcat = '';
    Object.keys(listOfObj).forEach(item =>{
      (listOfObj[item] === 1)? stringConcat += item : null
    });
    return stringConcat
  } @James

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this

```
const allConcat = (listOfObj) => {
    let stringConcat = '';
    Object.keys(listOfObj).map((item, i)=>{
      (listOfObj[item] === 1)? stringConcat += item : null
    });
    return stringConcat
  }
```

to this

```
const allConcat = (listOfObj) => Object.entries(listOfObj)
    .filter(([key, val]) => val === 1)
    .map(([key]) => key)
    .join('')
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can use array.reduce to achieve the same and not have to create the let constant or iterate twice:

```
const allConcat = (listOfObj) => 
 Object.keys(listOfObj).reduce((acc, curr, index, array) => 
  listOfObj[curr] === 1 ? acc.concat(array[index + 1] ? `${curr}, `: curr) : acc,
 '');
```

Comment: This is perfect. I would like to add a " ," between every key. Is there a way to do that for every item and not have a extra comma at the end of the string? @jean182